# How to fabricate a turnContext for testing Microsoft Botbuilder SDK?

Tags: node.js, testing, botframework

IDE: Visual Studio 2017
SDK: Botbuilder V4
Emulator: Bot-Framework Emulator V4
Language: Node.js v11

Hi all. I am making test cases for some largely static functions/methods of my bot code. However, I will later need to test more advanced functionality of my bot to test for specific behavior. Does anyone know how to fabricate some parts of the turnContext?

For example, I am fabricating my own right now by manually creating a simulated turnContext JSON in the following way:

```
turnContext {
activity: {
    text: "custom test text",
    channelID: "custom ID",
    conversation: {
        id: "custom ID" } } }
```

The problem is that this fabricated context doesn't actually have the inhereted methods like `turnContext.sendActivity('custom message');`. So my tests will be limited to only the most basic functionality of the bot that won't actually guarantee the entire behavior is performing as designed.

Comment: you could take a look at the Virtual Assistant bot where our team is working on how to implement unit tests to test the behavior of dialogs and flows of bots. There are tests in 2 locations in that bot currently in C#. Team will work on getting things into TS/JS in the future as well. 1.: https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/solutions/Virtual-Assistant/src/csharp/tests 2: then within each skill there's a test folder https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/solutions/Virtual-Assistant/src/csharp/skills

Comment: Also unit tests for the Enterprise bot, which there's currently a VSIX template out for is expected to be published on Thurs as well